# Golang Mgo pacing

Tags: go, mgo

I am writing an application which writes to the mongodb rapidly. Too rapidly for mongodb and mgo to handle. My question is, is there a way for me to determine that mongo cannot keep up and start to block? But I also do not want to block unnecessarily. 
Here is a sample of code that emulates the problem:

```
package main

import (
  "labix.org/v2/mgo"
  "time"
  "fmt"
)

// in database name is a string and age is an int

type Dog struct{
  Breed string "breed"
}

type Person struct{
  Name string "name"
  Pet Dog `bson:",inline"`
  Ts        time.Time
}

func insert(session *mgo.Session, bob Person){
  err := session.DB("db_log").C("people").Insert(&bob)
  if err != nil {
    panic("Could not insert into database")
  }
}

func main() {
  session, _ := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")
  bob := Person{Name : "Robert", Pet : Dog{}}
  i := 0
  for {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Microsecond)
    i++
    go insert(session, bob)
  }
}
```

I often get errors like:

```
panic: Could not insert into database
```

or

```
panic: write tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: i/o timeout
```

Comment: @EvanShaw what do your recommend instead?

Comment: It's hard to make a recommendation without knowing anything about the application in question, but PostgreSQL is often a good default choice.

Comment: If it's cool to write opinions, then I'm going to offer a contrary opinion to @EvanShaw. We use Mongo in production and love it. We get get great performance out of it. Don't let the haters mess with you. I have yet to hear an argument against Mongo that can't be countered. David Mytton at Server Density wrote [a terrific counterpoint](https://blog.serverdensity.com/does-everyone-hate-mongodb/) a year and a half ago that I recommend reading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you will get much better performance if you [allow Go to use multiple threads](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mgo-users/wkEE7LNpWpc) and [Copy() then Close()](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mgo-users/iZeiKgonGDU) your sessions.

To answer your question, this probably a perfect use-case for a channel. Feed the items into the channel in one goroutine and consume them/write them to Mongo in another. You can adjust the size of the channel to suit your needs. The producer thread will block once the channel is full when it tries to send to it.

You may also want to play with the [Safe()](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Session.Safe) method settings. Setting W:0 will put Mongo in a "fire and forget" mode, which will dramatically speed up performance at the risk of losing some data. You can also change the timeout time.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try it and get back to you tomorrow

Comment: I did try to use Copy() and then Close(). 
I got some errors that look like: 2014/01/27 18:28:36 http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:9090: too many open files; retrying in 1s

Comment: Also I have looked at Safe() parameter and am in a very unsafe mode, so it should be very quick

Comment: I dont quite understand the server limitation on tcp and what not. Also I have printed out my mgo.GetStats and it looks something like this:
{0 141 -140 339585 170373 170373 1 1 224}
And so it seems that is is one socketInUse.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using OSX? :-) You'll need to increase the [maximum file descriptors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/) in order to get more concurrent connections to Mongo.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help, I have learned a lot and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested yet but I think this code should work.
I get this issue after keep a session for long time so that I have timer to renew session every certain time.

```
package main

import (
  "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
  "time"
  "fmt"
)

// in database name is a string and age is an int

type Dog struct{
  Breed string "breed"
}

type Person struct{
  Name string "name"
  Pet Dog `bson:",inline"`
  Ts        time.Time
}

func insert(session *mgo.Session, bob Person){
  err := session.DB("db_log").C("people").Insert(&bob)
  if err != nil {
    panic("Could not insert into database")
  }
}

func main() {
  current_session, _ := mgo.Dial("localhost:27017")
  using_session := current_session
  bob := Person{Name : "Robert", Pet : Dog{}}

  /*
  * this technical to prevent connect timeout after long time connection on mongodb from golang session
  * Idea is simple: the session will be renew after certain time such as 1 hour
  */
  //ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Hour * 1)

  //Set 10 seconds for test
  ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 10)

  go func() {

    for t := range ticker.C {
      fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
      new_session := current_session.Copy()
      fmt.Printf("Current session here %p\n", current_session)
      fmt.Printf("New session here %p\n", new_session)
      using_session = new_session
      //setTimeout 30 second before close old sesion, to make sure current instance use current connection isn't affect
      //time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 30, func() { 

      //Set 2 seconds for test
      time.AfterFunc(time.Second * 2, func() { 

        //close previous session

        current_session.Close()
        current_session = new_session

        //assign to new session

      })

    }
  }()

  i := 0
  for {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(1) * time.Microsecond)
    i++
    go insert(using_session, bob)
  }

}
```